# What is this shrub in Colorado with white flowers and closely spaced small ovate leaves?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I've got this bush and I'd like to get a few more but I'm not sure what it's called. It has white flowers in early June. I'm in Colorado and it gets full sun.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, my guess is some kind of [Spirea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiraea). This extremely variable genus has some plants with a very similar growth habit, inflorescence, bloom time, leaf shape, and leaf placement of your shrub. If the shrub looked similar to the one pictured below when in bloom, you have a spirea.

[image]

Comment: I just saw a couple at the nursery. Looks like you're right -- Specifically, Snowmound Spirea.